# 'Errors' Partial works for 'New' user but not 'Edit' user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and 100% newb to coding.
Currently, I am getting this message:

> Extracted source (around line #1): undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
```

I only get this message in my edit.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @user %>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <%= form_for(@user, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :username %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Username", autofocus: true %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Email"  %>
                </div>
            </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :password %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Password"  %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <div class = "col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', class: "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class = "col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-5">
            [ <%= link_to 'Back to Index', articles_path %> ]
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

My new.html.erb has the exact same code but does not get the error message. This is the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def new 
      @user = User.new 
   end

   def create
       @user = User.new(user_params)
       if @user.save
           flash[:success] = "Welcome to Alpha Blog #{@user.username}"
           redirect_to articles_path
       else
           render 'new'
        end

    def edit
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end

    def update

    end
   end


    private

    def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password) 
    end
end
```

This is the errors partial:

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class ="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class ="panel-title">
                    <%= pluralize(obj.errors.count, "error") %>
                    prohibited this article from being saved:
                    </h2>
                    <div class ="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                             <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                <li><%= msg %></li>
                             <% end %>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Want to ask about the error. There should be something like: "Undefined method <method_name> for nil class". Is it correct? And if yes, please provide this error.

Comment: And want to ask about when this error is occured. When you got to "users/new" or after "users/create" worked with validation errors?

Comment: Add some stacktrace to the question?

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev just updated the post: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Well, I have 2 assumptions:
1. @user variable is not defined so it is nil. The request is sent from a different controller or you provided not a full code of your controllers.
To check it substitute `obj` in your partial on `@user`
2. `obj` is some kind of keyword. To check it substitute it on `error_model`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are doing a partial for this when there are plenty of gems and helpers to do this for you.

The problem is, you forgot `locals` and `partial`, as you can read in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/errors', locals: {obj: @user} %>
```

Personally I'd recommend to change `obj` to `object`, in rails we like to write-out words.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial. I tried doing what you suggested but still getting the same error message.

Comment: Partial and locals are not required according to rails guide. It is "Rendering the default case". I think the issue is in an instance variable.

Comment: @j_nguyen For debugging you put `<%= local_assigns %>` in your partial and remove the other code from it.

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev from the guide: _Also note that explicitly specifying :partial is required when passing additional options such as :layout._
When you just start out with Rails it helps to be a little more expressive and avoid the short-cuts for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `update` action is empty I mean no any valid code for the action, you can add some valid code for updating like below

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = 'User was successfully updated.'
            format.html { redirect_to @user }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Now try to check validation using incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i closed the "if" block in the Create Method but didn't close the Create Method itself.